# how to use pandas fillna NaN with the negative of the next row value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a table of daily (time series) rain of cities. how to use pandas fillna NaN by the negative of the next day rain of **the same city**? Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rain_before = pd.DataFrame({'date':Date*2,'city':list('aaaaabbbbb'),'rain':[6,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan]})

# after fillna, the table should look like this. 
rain_after_fillna = pd.DataFrame({'date':Date*2,'city':list('aaaaabbbbb'),'rain':[6,-1,1,np.nan,np.nan,4,np.nan,-8,8,np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you shift and fillna

```
rain_before['rain'].fillna(rain_before.groupby('city')['rain']
                           .transform(lambda x: -x.shift(-1)))

0    6.0
1   -1.0
2    1.0
3   NaN 
4   NaN 
5    4.0
6   NaN 
7   -8.0
8    8.0
9   NaN 
Name: rain, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks. it works! how to modify the codes if the 'rain' is 0 rather NaN. I want to get the same table. replace 0 with the negative of right next value. ```rain_before = pd.DataFrame({'date':Date*2,'city':list('aaaaabbbbb'),'rain':[6,0,1,0,0,4,0,0,8,0]})```

Comment: what is the expected value to replace with, if the right next value is 0,  -0?

Comment: 0 or -0. -0 is 0 anyway. so it doesn't mater.

Comment: You can used boolean indexing and shift as in the answer
`rain_after_fill_na.loc[rain_before['rain']==0, 'rain'] = -rain_before['rain'].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the series of `shift(-1)*-1`. There is no sample dataset so I've synthesized and not included city.  Same approach can be used for city,  sort order needs to be considered

```
import datetime as dt
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,1,1), dt.date(2021,1,10))
             ,"rainfall":[i*random.randint(0,1) for i in range(10)]}).replace({0:np.nan})

df["rainfall_nan"] = df["rainfall"].fillna(df["rainfall"].shift(-1)*-1)
```

### output

```
      Date  rainfall  rainfall_nan
2021-01-01       NaN          -1.0
2021-01-02       1.0           1.0
2021-01-03       2.0           2.0
2021-01-04       3.0           3.0
2021-01-05       NaN          -5.0
2021-01-06       5.0           5.0
2021-01-07       6.0           6.0
2021-01-08       7.0           7.0
2021-01-09       NaN          -9.0
2021-01-10       9.0           9.0
```